# WL.JSONStore.push does nothing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, adapter, synchronization, jsonstore

I'm using Worklight 6.2 to build a simple example of data sync using JSONStore and a SQL Adapter.
Everything seems to be working the way I want, except for the "push" back to the adapter. My application pulls data via the "load()". I allow the user to select an item, change it, and then "replace()" inside the collection. However, when I call "push()", nothing happens. No errors - nada. I'm hoping this is a simple "typo" problem, but I'm stumped at this point.

Any input would be GREATLY appreciated!

-bob-

Things that are working:

```
WL.JSONStore.init(),
WL.JSONStore.load(),
WL.JSONStore.findAll(),
WL.JSONStore.find(),
WL.JSONStore.replace(),
WL.JSONStore.pushRequiredCount()
```

What's not working is the last and most important:

```
WL.JSONStore.push();
```

Here's my sync code:

```
function syncWithServer(){
// THIS FIRST PART WORKS - YAY!!!!!
console.log ("Check for dirty records");
WL.JSONStore.get(employeeCollectionName).pushRequiredCount()
.then(function (numberOfDirtyDocuments) {
    alert("DIRTY: " + numberOfDirtyDocuments);
 })

.fail(function (errorObject) {
    alert (errorObject);
});

 / NOTHING HAPPENS AFTER THE LOG  - JUST FALLS THRU TO THE LAST CONSOLE LOG
// NO ERRORS OR ANYTHING

console.log("Atempting to update server");

WL.JSONStore.get(employeeCollectionName).push()
 .then ( function (res) {
    alert("Server updated successfully");
})
 .fail ( function (errorObject){
    alert (errorObject);
});
console.log("HUmmmmmm .....");
}
```

Comment: Do you get 0 dirty documents when you do the pushRequiredCount? Is the res variable in the push callback empty, or is the array full? Could you include your WL.JSONStore.init with the options object where you configure the adapter that you are going to use for pushing? What is the code in the adapter that you are pushing to? All these would be helpful to debug your code. Are you testing this code in Android, iOS, Windows or just in a browser while previewing? Can you see connection to the adapter in the logs? Can you reach the server's console from the device you are testing on?

Comment: @Daniel - apologies for the long delay. Unfortunately I had to travel all last week and had to shelve this. Before I send code, I think I need to rebuild my project with only the bare minimum elements - try to minimize the possibility for error. In the mean time, I noticed that the WL 6.1 and WL 6.2 samples do NOT use jQuery Mobile. I wonder if anyone has any thoughts on compatibility issues. I'm use JQM 1.4.0.

Comment: JQM should not be a problem, but if you take it out it might make debugging easier. Try to get the info I asked for so that we can narrow down what the problem is.

Comment: @Daniel - I get 1 dirty doc as expected, i never get the the callback, I'm testing on a MAC using FireFox and Chrome, the adapter is stubbed out now and i see the getEmployees, but not the updateEmployee. I've added (i hope) the files to a github (newbie)  account for your review - be kind! :-)  

https://github.com/btierney/SampleJSONStore

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, please look at my answer below which should make it work for you.

Comment: Please look at Namfo's answer below; it is working for us.

Answer (score 2):

Your application seems to be doing the right thing, so this could be a defect. However, the push() and load() API are deprecated as of 6.2, and I think that if you follow the new approach it will work for you.

The new approach is to call the adapter directly; this is all that JSONStore did anyways when you called push() or load(), while constraining you to what parameters you can send to it, so it makes more sense that you call the adapter directly. For push, you can edit your push call like this:

```
WL.JSONStore.get(employeeCollectionName).getAllDirty()

.then(function (dirtyDocs) {

  return WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
    adapter : 'people',
    procedure : 'updatePeople',
    parameters : [ dirtyDocs ]
  });
})

.then(function (responseFromAdapter) {
  // ... call markClean API after a valid response form the adapter
});
```

Making sure to change the parameters and procedure and adapter name to your adapter's.

Also, this answer is a very short summary of what is in the documentation for [working with external data](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_external_data.html?lang=en), including examples on how to do push and pull (load).

That said, even though push() and load() are deprecated, they should still work, so a defect has been created to look further into this.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your test app from you GitHub account and I was able to run it fine using an HTTP adapter and the callbacks returning correctly. Which logs did you receive when using an SQL adapter, if any.

[EDIT ~ 8/6] I created an SQL adapter and was able to push and pull from the adapter.